# Find custom html tag in string using regex, separate text and image url in array

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, image

I have a requirement where I need to extract urls from body. I want to remove the tags from original body and add them in sequence to the array.

for e.g. I want to convert this string -

```
Muffin powder chocolate candy jelly icing cotton candy. Oat cake
danish bear claw tootsie roll donut pie. Toffee chupa chups brownie
cupcake pudding sweet roll dessert jelly-o. <blobUrl=https://google.com/img1.png> Gummies macaroon pudding
marzipan. Chocolate cake biscuit muffin tart jelly-o carrot cake.
Liquorice dessert gummi bears icing danish. Ice cream marshmallow
candy marzipan cupcake. Sweet lollipop dragée chocolate cheesecake
chocolate gummies sesame snaps. <blobUrl=https://google.com/img with space.png> Lollipop jelly bear claw danish jelly
beans chocolate. Pudding cake gingerbread dessert halvah jelly
marzipan. Gingerbread oat cake dragée cake cake marzipan. Oat cake
lemon drops pudding bear claw soufflé lollipop biscuit pudding.
```

To array collection, something like this  -

```
arrayVariable[0] = "Muffin powder chocolate candy jelly icing cotton candy. Oat cake danish bear claw tootsie roll donut pie. Toffee chupa chups brownie
cupcake pudding sweet roll dessert jelly-o.

arrayVariable[1] = "https://google.com/img1.png"

arrayVariable[2] = "Gummies macaroon pudding
marzipan. Chocolate cake biscuit muffin tart jelly-o carrot cake.
Liquorice dessert gummi bears icing danish. Ice cream marshmallow
candy marzipan cupcake. Sweet lollipop dragée chocolate cheesecake
chocolate gummies sesame snaps."

arrayVariable[3] = "https://google.com/img with space.png"

arrayVariable[4] = "Lollipop jelly bear claw danish jelly
beans chocolate. Pudding cake gingerbread dessert halvah jelly
marzipan. Gingerbread oat cake dragée cake cake marzipan. Oat cake
lemon drops pudding bear claw soufflé lollipop biscuit pudding."
```

So far I tried using this regex

```
    var bodyToParse = bodyText;

    string re1 = ".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
    string re2 = "((?:http|https)(?::\\/{2}[\\w]+)(?:[\\/|\\.]?)(?:[^\\s\"]*))";    // HTTP URL 1

    Regex r = new Regex(re1 + re2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
    Match m = r.Match(bodyToParse);
    if (m.Success)
    {
        String httpurl1 = m.Groups[1].ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine("(" + httpurl1.ToString() + ")" + "\n");
    }
```

Which works well but can not figure out how to separate everything in to list of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this snippet. It might not be the best, but it should get all your URLs and assemble all the parts of text into a `List<string>` variable `lst`:

```
var tststr = @"Muffin powder chocolate candy jelly icing cotton candy. Oat cake
danish bear claw tootsie roll donut pie. Toffee chupa chups brownie
cupcake pudding sweet roll dessert jelly-o. <blobUrl=https://google.com/img1.png> Gummies macaroon pudding
marzipan. Chocolate cake biscuit muffin tart jelly-o carrot cake.
Liquorice dessert gummi bears icing danish. Ice cream marshmallow
candy marzipan cupcake. Sweet lollipop dragée chocolate cheesecake
chocolate gummies sesame snaps. <blobUrl=https://google.com/img with space.png> Lollipop jelly bear claw danish jelly
beans chocolate. Pudding cake gingerbread dessert halvah jelly
marzipan. Gingerbread oat cake dragée cake cake marzipan. Oat cake
lemon drops pudding bear claw soufflé lollipop biscuit pudding.";
var lst = new List<string>();
var former_idx = 0;
for (var m = Regex.Match(tststr, @"\s*<blobUrl=(http[^>]+)>\s*"); m.Success; m = m.NextMatch())
{
    lst.Add(tststr.Substring(former_idx, m.Index - former_idx));
    lst.Add(m.Groups[1].Value);
    former_idx = m.Index + m.Value.Length;
}
if (former_idx < tststr.Length)
    lst.Add(tststr.Substring(former_idx, tststr.Length - former_idx));
```